# do while loop, adding multiple conditions

Tags: c, do-while

Hi everyone I am trying to add multiple conditions to a do while statement with the code shown as followed

```
do

 ( switch case menu)

while(choice!='X' && (NetworkPacket= 50; printf("No more network packets can be added")));
```

Basically, the (some code) part is a menu system which asks the user to add packets of data, then the choice!='x' allows the user to exit the program by pressing x. But as the menu allows them to loop through, I want the program to also restrict the user from adding more than 50 packets hence the network packet int = 50 then it says no more packets can be added but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please edit your post  and rewrite this without that awkward last compound statement. It makes not much sense as it is now.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute a statement as part of a condition. It can be done, but it's not usually considered good practice because it tends to result in rather awkward (and bug-prone) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
do
{
     (switch case menu)
     NetworkPacket++;
}

 while(choice!='X' && (NetworkPacket >= 50? printf("No more network packets can be added" ),0 : 1));
```

Comment: error: syntax error before ':' token. Also i should mention the Network Packet integer is just adding as a counter so every time the user loops through the menu adding a packet, it just adds 1

Comment: ok, my error with a few extra }, but this seems to work, thanks for the insight, but what does the ? and the 0:1 do?

Comment: That's a good question. `?:` is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). `,` is a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). When `NetworkPacket >= 50` becomes true, `printf` executed and the whole expression becomes `false` by `0` after the `,`. If the condition is false then value of the whole expression after `?` becomes `1` by the `1` after `:`

Answer (score 3):

Stylistically, your code will be easier to read if the `while` statement only has logic, and actions like `printf` are outside. You can separate out the parts like this:

```
#define PACKET_LIMIT 50
do {
    (switch case menu)
    //presumably NetworkPackets is being updated in here too
} while ((choice != 'X') && (NetworkPackets < PACKET_LIMIT));

//now check why we exited
if (NetworkPackets >= PACKET_LIMIT) {
    printf("No more network packets can be added");
}
```

Using `< PACKET_LIMIT` in the loop logic allows for the case where multiple packets might be added by the loop body.